# Стает или становится?

Tags: устаревшие-слова

Читала в разных словарях, что слово "ставать" и все производные от него в современной речи уже практически не употребляются, а на замену ему пришло слово "становиться". Не будет ли ошибкой употребление в речи устаревшего "стаёт"? Например, в таком предложении: "К сожалению, из-за глобального потепления этих пингвинов стаёт все меньше"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это некорректное утверждение. *"Стал"* - прошедшее время совершенного вида от *"ставал"* вполне себе употребляется. Более того, оно используется как супплетивная форма для совершенного вида от "становился". Но тем не менее остается "производной формой" от *"ставал*".

От неё же - приставочная форма *"вставать", "вставал"*.

А в несовершенном виде - да, бесприставочные формы от *"ставать"* сейчас считаются устаревшими. Но не все. В безличной форме *"А он, ставало, ходил на охоту"* (аналогично *"бывало"*) и в некоторых контекстах для выражения многократности (включая причастия: *стававший* = многократно становящийся) еще не до конца потеряли актуальность.

И еще одно. У "*ставать", "ставало"* было еще одно, едва ли не главное, значение: "быть достаточным". Оно сейчас заменено синонимичным *"хваать", "хватало"*. Так что тут тоже формулировка некорректная.

Примеры есть в нацкорпусе. Позвольте мне их здесь опустить за очевидностью.

Answer (score 2):

Такое употребление, действительно, сегодня считается уже устаревшим.

ставать, стаёт **(устар. и обл. к становиться (каким)** и доставать (быть в достаточном количестве, хватать).

**См.: Русский орфографический словарь Российской академии наук.
Отв. ред. В. В. Лопатин.**

Поэтому в современных текстах (а ваш пример именно к такому относится)  употребление этого слова считается некорректным.